# Implement one general Authorization Service which should be called when I put Authorize attribute on it in multiple applications/APIs

Tags: identityserver4, identity, policy-server

Has anyone an idear what to use as a general Authorization Service and have an working code example or good implementation steps how to implement such of thing.

It takes a lot of time to look what I am after, but didn't found any satisfied solution yet.

IdentityServer is not an option, while my permissions can not be stored as claims, because of the size of the token. It comes with about 200 persmissions, so it should be done in a dbcontext or something.

I looked at the PolicyServer, but it wasn't working as I expected. When I installed it at the IS4 application, it works on the IS4 controllers, but when the Authorize is called from an external application, it doesn't call the Authorize override at all were it should check the permissions.
And it seems that the permissions aren't set in the external application either in the User.Claims or what so ever. I'm missing some settings I think.

What I want to accomplish is that I have one permissions store (table) (which for example contains a bunch of index, add, edit or delete button or what so ever). The should be given to the autheniticated user which is logged in. But this single persmission-store should be available at all applications or APIs I run, so that the Authorize attribute can do his job.

I think it shouldn't be so hard to do, so I'm missing a good working example how to implement something like this and what is working.
Who can help me with this to get this done?

I wrote some code to get the permissions by API call and use that in the IsInRole override. But when I declare it with the Authorize attr, it will not get in the method:

```cs
[ApiController]
1) [Authorize]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IdentityContext _context;
public AuthController(IdentityContext context)
{
   _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
}

[HttpGet()]
[Route("api/auth/isinrole")]
public bool IsInRole(string role)
{
2) if (User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value != null)
   {
      var userID = Guid.Parse(User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value);
      if([This is the code that checks if user has role])
         return true;
   }
   return false;
```

This is the IsInRole override (ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole override):

```cs
public override bool IsInRole(string role)
{
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("AuthClient");
3)  var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken).Result; 

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/auth/isinrole/?id=" + role);
    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

etc...
```

1. This isn't working while it is not sending the access_token in the request
2. The 'sub' isn't send
3. Is always null

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to your solution and that is to use a **referense token** instead of a JWT-token. A reference token is just an opaque identifier and when a client receives this token, he has go to and look up the real token and details via the backend. The reference token does not contain any information. Its just a lookup identifier that the client can use against IdentiyServer

By using this your tokens will be very small.

Using reference token is just one option available to you.

see the documentation about [Reference Tokens](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html)

Comment: You mean [reference token](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html)?

Comment: Yes! I will fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

The open source version of the PolicyServer is a *local* implementation. All it does is read the permissions from a store (in the sample a config file) and transform them into claims using middleware.

In order to use the permissions you'll have to add this middleware *in all projects* where you want to use the permissions.

Having local permissions, you can't have conflicts with other resources. E.g. being an admin in api1 doesn't mean you are admin in api2 as well.

But decentralized permissions may be hard to maintain. That's why you probably want a central server for permissions, where the store actually calls the policy server rather than read the permissions from a local config file.

For that you'll need to add a discriminator in order to distinguish between resources. I use *scopes*, because that's the one thing that both the client and the resource share.

It also keeps the response small, you only have to request the permissions for a certain scope instead of all permissions.

The alternative is to use IdentityServer as-is. But instead of JWT tokens use [reference tokens](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html).

The random string is a lot shorter, but requires the client and / or resource to request the permissions by sending the reference token to the IdentityServer. This may be close to how the PolicyServer works, but with less control on the response.

Comment: Hi, tnx for your answer. 
Can you give me some code examples how to implement this whole idear of yours? 
I asume that I'm not restricted to any limitations somehow, because claims are limited in size. In my case a user can have say +250 permissions.

Comment: Cookies and headers are limited in size, not the claims or the tokens. Bypassing them will remove the limitations. I don't have code for you, but I'm sure you can write a user authorization endpoint that returns the permissions that are part of a scope. For the clients/resources you can use the sample code from the OSS version of the PolicyServer where the json config file is replaced with a HttpClient call to the server endpoint, requesting the permissions for the allowed scopes only. Use a local cache to improve performance.

Comment: I think you mean to create an API method that returns if a user has the permission. 
And then call this API in the ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole override by using a HttpClient. Correct?

Comment: The endpoint is an API method, but the override is prior to IsInRole. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/PolicyServer.Local/AspNetCore/PolicyServerMiddleware.cs#L37) you can customize the code to read the claims from your own store, e.g. `var claims = await authStore.GetClaimsAsync();` where the store initializes the httpClient and makes the actual call to the API. In the next lines the claims are added to the collection of a new Identity that is added to the claims principal, the source for policies and IsInRole.

Comment: Hi, I think I'm looking for something that is easier to understand. I'm new at this Security/Identity/Token stuff. I'm learning from working samples, preffer Dutch. 
So I added some code in the question which I'm using now. But is not working yet becasue the auth tokens are not send with the request. I'm missing something.

Comment: If you aren't hitting limits yet then ignore this for now and focus on learning first. Otherwise try reference tokens. Just change the token type: `client.AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference;`.

Comment: There is no need to override IsInRole at all, so don't use that code. Like I said before, add the permissions (and roles, which are in fact also claims of the claimtype 'role') to the ClaimsPrincipal using middleware. Then you can use IsInRole without having to override it.The reason that the sub is null may be because the endpoint isn't secured. Otherwise without token the endpoint wouldn't be hit in the first place. Add [Authorize] and try again.